# laravel 6 Route not working after adding localization

Tags: laravel

in my we site Route running well be four adding localization.

I add here one of A tag that I used ,
`<a href="/viewadd?gender=Female">`
this is working with on web.php .

```
Route::get('/viewadd', 'AddController@index' );
```

but after adding localization this route not working
and also login route.

after that I change login route like this.

```
<a class="" href="{{ route('login', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
```

this one is working. running well

but I Do same thing to other A tag. but that not working. here I add that not working code

```
<a href="{{ route('viewadd', app()->getLocale()) }}">.
```

erroer massage is

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewExceptio-Route [viewadd] not defined. (View: /home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

and also I need pass one parameeter to backend loke this. that also add here

```
<a href="/viewadd?gender=Female">
```

hoping your help soon. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the alias you're trying to use to your route:

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/viewadd', 'AddController@index' )->name('viewadd');
```

Now you can use it in the helper `route`:

```html
<a href="{{ route('viewadd', [app()->getLocale(), 'gender' => 'Female'] ) }}">.
```

The login/logout routes (when you use `Auth::routes()`) have defined aliases.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::alias does not exist.

Comment: @sameera use `name()` instead

Comment: can you explain what I want to do? step by step. Im new to laravel

Comment: @sameera i've edited my answer. just define the route as in the answer

Comment: cool its work, how to add parameter to that link , like this <a href="/viewadd?gender=Female">

Comment: @sameera you can add it in the second parameter: `{{ route('viewadd', [app()->getLocale(), 'gender' => 'Female']) }}`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' (View: /home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/resources/views/index.blade.php)

Comment: @sameera you did not copy a `]` after `'Female'`. it's just a syntax error.

Comment: @sameera dont forget to set it as the answer to your question (and upvote if it's perfect for you)